# How do I forward all email address from a .com to .com.au domains

Tags: email-server

I have 2 domains one with domain.com and domain.com.au. I am wondering whether its possible to automatically forward the emails from someone@domain.com.au to someone@domain.com without manually creating the emails and setting up the forwarding on the .com.au domain.

I have got a hmailserver installed on IIS environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is called a Domain Alias

The current docs are on the hmailserver website:
http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/v4.2/?page=feature_domainname_aliases

1. Start hMailAdmin.
2. Expand the Domains node and select the domain (e.g. mydomain.com).
3. Select the Names tab.
4. Add the domain names to the list (e.g. mydomain.org and mydomain.net)